# How to develop authentication with resteasy?

Tags: java, authentication, rest, web-services, resteasy

I'm making small web service(1) and I decided to use resteasy to make it. But I need to know what would be best practise to develop authentication with resteasy. And what kind of responses webservice should  send? Are responses usually in XML or what format, and what format of XML response should be?

Btw. I use jboss 4 and Java 5.

http://www.assertionerror.com/2009/02/26/restful-web-services-with-resteasy/

(1) [What technology I should use to develop small Java webservice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803446/what-technology-i-should-use-to-develop-small-java-webservice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Authentication: http://www.jboss.org/file-access/default/members/resteasy/freezone/docs/1.2.GA/userguide/html/Authentication.html
- What kind of responses? What's suitable for your application; XML, atom, plaintext, ...
- Response need not to be XML, see `@Produces("your-content-type")` annotation

Answer (score 3):

For the authentication you can use the Interceptor (classes that are invoked before the RESTEasy annotated class), see

- [RESTEasy Interceptors](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.0.GA/userguide/html/Interceptors.html)
- [Authentication in RESTEasy](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.0.GA/userguide/html/Authentication.html)
- [client ip in interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699549/resteasy-security-interceptor-how-to-obtain-client-ip-address-inside-intercept/9065769#9065769)

I'm developing a big application, and I'm using Interceptors for the authentication