# Resteasy security interceptor - how to obtain client IP address inside interceptor?

Tags: java

I have implemented an interceptor to carry out a security check on the client IP address with the following annotations -
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
@Precedence("SECURITY")

The preprocess method takes the parameters HttpRequest request, ResourceMethod method.
Is there a way of obtaining the client's IP address from the Resteasy HttpRequest object?
I can implement a filter to get around this, but would like to keep security checks in the one place.

Answer (score 1):

The client IP address is available from the request object. But you can't use that for security purposes as it isn't unique per client: it might just be the address of the nearest proxy, even your own.

Comment: This is something we are going to have to live with for now. Can you tell me how to get the IP address from org.jboss.resteasy.spi.HttpRequest?

Comment: This is true and generally for Java Servlets and other systems. Their reference point for the HTTP header client (remote) Address (IP) is only the nearest hop - not the source. Best to do this in a front-end router and control a custom header that can then be parsed on the Java side (reliably).

Answer (score 0):

This (my) answer is wrong!
The HttpServletRequest is "injected" only when the filter class is instantiated, so the instance "see" the same HttpServletRequest for all the subsequent requests (the HttpServletREquest is always the first!!!!!)

---

You can inject the HttpServletRequest object to access the client ip (I'm using it)

```
@Provider
@Interceptor
@Precedence("SECURITY")
public class JAXRSInterceptor implements PreProcessInterceptor
{

    **@Context HttpServletRequest request; // WRONG WRONG WRONG**

    @Override
    public ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest arg0, ResourceMethod arg1) throws Failure, WebApplicationException
    {


        System.out.println(request.getRemoteAddr());
        System.out.println(request.getRemoteHost());
    }
```