# Resteasy PreProcessInterceptor for logging request attributes (not parameters)

Tags: resteasy

We're using JBoss and Resteasy to implement a web service, and one requirement is that we log parameters and attributes passed to the web service before processing starts.  the PreProcessInterceptor is ideal for this.  I have it working and logging the request *parameters* just fine, but some of the information is going to be passed as attributes, and I can't work out how to access them.

Below is the code I use to log the request parameters; can anyone tell me how to get the attributes as well?

```
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
public class ParameterLoggingInterceptor implements PreProcessInterceptor {
    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

@Override
public ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest request, ResourceMethod method) throws UnauthorizedException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> mMap = request.getUri().getQueryParameters();
    Set<String> keys = mMap.keySet();
    int mapSize = keys.size();
    if (mapSize > 0) {
        sb.append("Incoming parameters: ");
        int processedParams = 1; 
        for (String key : keys) {
            sb.append(key).append("=");
            sb.append(mMap.get(key));
            if (processedParams < mapSize) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            processedParams++;
        }
        logger.debug(sb.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

Edited to add the following in response to Eiden's answer:

Thanks, Eiden.  I just gave it a try.  Do you mean something like the following?  If so, it doesn't seem to work (and if not, please clarify). What attributeName provides is: "org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractConversationContext", and attributeValue is the same. This is the same result I got when using the org.jboss.resteasy.spi.HttpRequest object.

```
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
public class ParameterLoggingInterceptor implements PreProcessInterceptor {
    @Context HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

@Override
public ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest request, ResourceMethod method) throws UnauthorizedException {
    Enumeration<String> attributeNames = servletRequest.getAttributeNames();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (attributeNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String attributeName = (String) attributeNames.nextElement();
        String attributeValue = (String) servletRequest.getAttribute(attributeName);
        // Do something with attributeValue and attributeName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

RestEasy can inject the `HttpServletRequest` into your interceptor:

```
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
public class ParameterLoggingInterceptor implements PreProcessInterceptor {
    @javax.ws.rs.core.Context HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

}
```

Then you can access the `HttpServletRequest` directly from the `preProcess`-method and extract the data necessary to fulfill your logging requirements.

Comment: Thanks, Eiden.  I've edited my question, above, to show what happened when I tried this; not sure if I've correctly implemented your answer, so please take a look.

Comment: See also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699549/resteasy-security-interceptor-how-to-obtain-client-ip-address-inside-intercept

Comment: PreProcessInterceptor is deprecated now, what is the new way? http://stackoverflow.com/q/31240026/1694323