# how to log resteasy client request

Tags: logging, resteasy, interceptor

I need to know what is exactly the REST message body before sending it to client and also its response before processing, so I try to use [Interceptors](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html/Interceptors.html#d4e1377) but unfortunately it is **NOT** working.

```
        @NameBinding
        public @interface DoIt {}

        @DoIt
        public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {...}

        @Path("/root")
        public class MyResource {

           @GET
           @DoIt
           public String get() {...}
        }
```

I can not use wireshark to capture http messages because my server only accept Https requests.

I searched a lot and find many ways to logging, in Resteasy but most of them are old and deprecated and the new way as above is not working.
anyone know how to solve the problem?

RestEasy 3.0.9

JBoss EAP 6.3 with updated restEasy to 3.0.9

Thanks

Edit:

I test @Privider for ContainerRequestFilter too.

also for my interface

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@NameBinding
```

and also add this to web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>com.mypackage.RequestMessageLogger</param-value>
</context-param>
```

still filter is not called.

Comment: Which application server are you using?

Comment: Are you definitely sure that the update really worked?

Comment: yes, my request is sended and I receive response completely. I need the log for a complicated request that is not working and i think my request is missing something.

Comment: Just unsure if you are really running the newer version or the original one which does not know a ContainerRequestFilter.

Comment: In that way I should see class not found, runtime error, but no.

Comment: I'd also expect some errors but just to be sure try to log something like `Link.fromPath("/foo/{bar}").build("baz")` in any resource class.

Answer (score 0):

Your ContainerRequestFilter is missing the `@Provider` annotation. From the [api-docs](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-rev-a/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html):

> Filters implementing this interface must be annotated with [@Provider](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-rev-a/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/Provider.html) to be discovered by the JAX-RS runtime.

This should work:

```java
@DoIt
@Provider
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {...}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Is the Filter not called? What are you doing inside this Filter? Have you tried without the `@DoIt` annotations?

Comment: filter function is not called at all, inside the filter i have a print log for test.