# User Login Authentication in RESTEasy java

Tags: java, authentication, jakarta-ee, resteasy

I want to make user Login Authentication in my web application. I am using RESTEasy restful framwork. I want to do advance login system that will generate token, make an email to user for verification url. I have done Cross site authentication of twitter,google,FB using [socialauth](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/) lib. I want to know that is there any built in lib available in RESTEasy to make user login authentication and session management? or Can anybody suggest any lib which will provide all this functionality of user Login Management?

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807781/how-to-develop-authentication-with-resteasy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resteasy is just a JAX-RS implementation to help you build Restful APIs. It is not concerned with authentication and authorization because you handle that with your own method or libraries such as Apache Shiro. Also take a look at OAuth:

http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.2.1.GA/userguide/html/Authentication.html